# (C/Windows) Unable to unload driver

Tags: c, windows, driver

My OP is Windows 7 64bit. I'm loading a driver with DSEfix (Bypasses the Driver Sign Enforcement from Windows) and that works just fine. IOCTL Requests get executed they way they should, but whenever I try to unload my driver it fails on: `ControlService(hService, SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, &ss` with error code of Invalid Handle.

Here is my Driver Entry:

```
NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT Object, PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath) {

UNICODE_STRING dNUS = { 0 };
RtlInitUnicodeString(&dNUS, L"\\Device\\testdriver");

UNICODE_STRING dSLU = { 0 };
RtlInitUnicodeString(&dSLU, L"\\DosDevices\\testdriver");

IoCreateDevice(Object, 0, &dNUS, FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, FILE_DEVICE_SECURE_OPEN, FALSE, &deviceObj);
IoCreateSymbolicLink(&dSLU, &dNUS);

Object->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CREATE] = CCreate;
Object->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CLOSE] = CClose;
Object->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL] = IOCTL;
Object->DriverUnload = Unload;

return(STATUS_SUCCESS);
```

and the Unload function:

```
NTSTATUS Unload(PDRIVER_OBJECT Object) {
UNICODE_STRING symLink;
RtlInitUnicodeString(&symLink, L"\\DosDevices\\testdriver");

if (Object->DeviceObject != NULL)
{
    IoDeleteSymbolicLink(&symLink);
    IoDeleteDevice(Object->DeviceObject);
}
```

On the usermode side of things I get the hSCManager from `OpenSCManagerA(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE)` when loading the driver and hService from `CreateServiceA`. Both are valid and work for loading the driver just fine.

And here is my unload driver function in usermode:

```
bool UnloadDriver()
{
if (!hSCManager) return false;
if (!hService) return false;

cout << "STOPPING DRIVER" << endl;

SERVICE_STATUS ss;
if (ControlService(hService, SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, &ss))
{
    if (ss.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_STOPPED)
    {
        DeleteService(hService);
        CloseServiceHandle(hSCManager);
        CloseServiceHandle(hService);
        cout << "DRIVER UNLOADED" << endl;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "SERVICE NOT STOPPED IN TIME" << endl;
        CloseServiceHandle(hSCManager);
        CloseServiceHandle(hService);
        return false;
    }
}
else
{
    cout << "SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP FAILED" << endl;
    CloseServiceHandle(hSCManager);
    CloseServiceHandle(hService);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: *ControlService* fails with error code of Invalid Handle - so `The specified handle was not obtained using CreateService or OpenService, or the handle is no longer valid.` - what is here unclear ? you use *hService* as global variable which already very ugly and not professional for this code. how you obtaining this handle, are it not changed or closed - not visible - you not paste related code

Comment: @RbMm As I wrote, I'm obtaining the handle with CreateServiceA. And it works for loading and IOCTL with the Driver. For Unloading however it becomes unvalid? I could try to get it again with OpenService, but I don't see why the handle would be different.

Comment: but error code say by self. from another side you can direct call [ZwUnloadDriver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff567117(v=vs.85).aspx) - which *NTSTATUS* it return and what result ? and why your *hService* is global variable ?!?

Comment: Well, I have 2 different cpp's, one with all the functions themselves, Loading Driver, Unloading Driver, Enable DSE.... and then I have the cpp which calls all of the functions in the correct order. I don't actually know why it would be a disadvantage to have the variables global, I'd like to know though :)

Comment: And I just tryed ZmUnloadDriver, literally the same result. Once again Invalid Handle. What kind of confuses me is that if I try 'OpenServiceA(hSCManager, Driver, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);', the returned Handle is invalid.. but I don't know why, because my Driver is running.

Comment: `ZwUnloadDriver` return *STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE* ?! which **exactly** code returned ? and may be you delete driver registry key ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, as RbMm mentioned, I overlooked the removal of the Registry key... Well, but after I moved that code, I was still not able to unload my driver.

So I figured out that the SC_HANDLE obtained by CreateService is invalid. Eventhough it says on MSDN that the handle can be used from CreateService, it didn't work for me (might be DSE). You should instead just create a new SCManager and a new SCService and you should be good to go. Now ControlService is returning true for me :)